# Is "Fool around" used as an euphemism for "build a relationship" nowadays?

Tags: american-english

In old Western movies such as True Grit, "Fool around" was used as a substitute for "build a relationship between a man and a woman", is it still used in modern American English?

Comment: Actually, "build a relationship between a man and a woman" sounds like more of a euphemism to me than "fool around (with)". While the latter expression is technically indirect, its meaning in a sexual sense is so well-established that it sounds more explicit than you might think (I don't mean to say that it's R-rated or anything, but only that, like "intercourse", I think it no longer sounds  much like a euphemism).

Comment: In the US, "fool around" (in the right context) refers to having relations of a sexual nature.  It does not necessarily imply intercourse (though that is usually the implication), nor does it necessarily imply some sort of elicit relationship.  Of course, the term can also be used in somewhat different sense, as in "In my spare time I like to fool around with motorcycles."

Comment: Oops!  Make that "illicit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the idiomatic expression [fool around](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/fool-around)   used with a sexual connotation is mainly  an American English one:

​

> ***(mainly us)*** If a married person fools around, they have a sexual relationship with someone who is not their husband or wife:
>
> - *She'd been fooling around with someone at work.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

This usage is from the '70s according to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fool)

> 1970s in sense of "have sexual adventures."

Comment: It definitely is much older than the 70s, in my recollection.